# IOS: Add a Home Widget from inside my App

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I would like to add a widget to the home screen directly from the App.

Right now the user can go from the home screen to the widgets menu, search for the app widgets and add the one he likes, but it is way more complicated than it should since the user should be prompted to create it from inside the app.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about a widget made with `WidgetKit`?

Comment: Yes, with WidgetKit!

Comment: Not possible. It really sounds like a feature that can be easily exploited, so I’m glad it’s not a thing.

Comment: Would be the equivalent of `appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget` in Android that asks the user if he wants to add a widget, which is not been exploited.

Comment: Wish there was a method for this. Many users don’t know how to add widgets in iOS. At least a button that takes you to the ”add widget”-view.

Comment: Any code for creating widget using pure Swift, not SiwftUI ?